# How to sync read-only oneNote notebook from mac which was originally shared by another user (the another user doesn't exist now)

Tags: onenote

I've a Notebook in mac (Microsoft OneNote for Mac version: 16.16.27 (201012)).

This notebook was originally shared by another user. I had synced it to the mac few years back.

Now that user doesn't exist.

When I open that notebook in mac, one note displays the message: "Notebook is read-only. Copy content from here to another location to edit it."

I want to store this notebook to my account but one note is NOT showing any such options.

I cannot access this onenote online because the link to that onenote points to another user's drive, and that user has left the organization, so getting "404 FILE NOT FOUND" while attempting to access it online.

Any guidance on how to revive the notebook?

(Last resort is to copy the pages one by one in mac to another notebook, but the number of pages is large enough to find some automatic way to get this done. There seems to be no clean way of cloning the notebook in one note mac either.)

Related: Later posted on MS office community: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-sync-read-only-onenote-notebook-from-mac/04812e5d-5b80-4966-bc47-d9ccb6cdcb4f .

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://askdifferent.com/

Comment: The latest version of OneNote for Mac stores local backups of loaded notebooks - does this help? Pages are stored in sections which are basically .one files. Maybe copying a section to another notebook will allow cloud access?

Answer (score 0):

You can install chrome extensions to copy content from any website and then use OneNote Web version and open that read only file there, now through chrome extension to select all content of your large file and copy it to new file in a single go.

Extensions you can use :-
**Copy As Plain Text -** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-as-plain-text/eneajgkmdhmjmloiabgkpkiooaejmlpk

**Allow Select And Copy -** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-select-and-copy/lamaakaemgdclpnfbofmhpkanfnojjch

Thank You